# Summernote dynamic contents in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I created dropdownnemu:

```
var format = function (context) {
var ui = $.summernote.ui;

// create button
var buttonGroup = ui.buttonGroup([
    ui.button({
        className: 'dropdown-toggle dropdown-format',
        contents: 'Формат',
        tooltip: 'Формат листа для печати',
        container: false,
        data: {
            toggle: 'dropdown'
        },
        click: function() {

            context.invoke('editor.saveRange');
        }
    }),
    ui.dropdown({
        className: 'dropdown-menu dropdown-formatlist',
      contents:"<a class=\"dropdown-item\" >A5</a>",

        callback: function ($dropdown) {
            $dropdown.find('a').each(function () {
                $(this).click(function(e) {
                    var format = $(this).text();  
                        $(".dropdown-format").text(format);
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

            });


        }
    })
]);
return buttonGroup.render();   // return button as jquery object
```

};

Everything is okey.But if i adding dynamic content after ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
        ....
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $('.dropdown-menu').prepend("<a class=\"dropdown-item\">"+data.data+"</a>")

    });
```

*dropdown-item* inserted in html (.dropdown-menu),but when i click on this *dropdown-item* nothing happens. How add dynamic content on Summernote ?

Comment: Do you need to attach the event handler to the dynamically created `<a>`s?

Comment: @madebydavid may be. I don't sure:)

Comment: @ruslan were you able to solve this?